# La primera vez que entra al bucle for me lo itera dos veces

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Lo dicho, la primera vez que entra al bucle for me lo itera dos veces. Luego sigue normal pero así no me cuenta la primera.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //a uno se le van presentando personas desconocidas exactas con "soy -----" y va respondiendo "hola ------"
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int  n;
    String nombre;

    System.out.println("¿Cuántas personas desconoce?");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    String[] desconocidos = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < desconocidos.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Soy ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();
        desconocidos[i] = nombre;
    }
    sc.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < desconocidos.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Hola, "+desconocidos[i]);
    }

}
```

ejemplo de salida:

```
¿Cuántas personas desconoce?
4
Soy Soy juan
Soy alberto
Soy carlos
Hola, 
Hola, juan
Hola, alberto
Hola, carlos
```

Un soy no lo coge bien y se me queda vacio, tendría que poder poner los 4 nombres.

Comment: Prueba a poner después de sc.nextInt(); sc.next(); ya que al coger un entero con nextInt deja el buffer de entrada abierto (algo así me suena que era).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un `sc.nextLine()` justo despues de tu `sc.nextInt()` para que el programa no asigne el intro que haces con el valor a la siguiente petición.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //a uno se le van presentando personas desconocidas exactas con "soy -----" y va respondiendo "hola ------"
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int  n;
    String nombre;

    System.out.println("¿Cuántas personas desconoce?");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //  **** Esta es la linea que te falta ****

    String[] desconocidos = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < desconocidos.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Soy ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();
        desconocidos[i] = nombre;
    }
    sc.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < desconocidos.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Hola, "+desconocidos[i]);
    }

}
```